# How to deploy Tyrus (JSR 356 implementation) to a web container?

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, websocket, tyrus

I am attempting to deploy Tyrus to a Tomcat 8 container and am failing. According to the documentation, I should be able to deploy a WAR containing my classes and supporting Tyrus classes/dependencies and all classes annotated with @ServerEndpoint should be found in the WAR and deployed as websocket end points.  This instruction threw me a little because I'm not defining any sort of filter in the deployment descriptor but decided that I must be somehow depending on some unknown magic in the support of JSR 356 in Tomcat 8.  As it turns out, there is no such magic.  NOTE: I'm using Tomcat 8 because my understanding is that it supports the JSR 356 websocket standard.  Also, my JDK is the latest Java 7 version.

I have spent some time researching this and have found that people are successful in publishing websocket end points with Tyrus by running an instance of a Server (org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server) as a Java application from the command line.  I have tried this and it works.  However, I'm unable to find any success deploying a WAR on Tomcat.

Does anyone have any insight into the steps required to successfully publish websocket end points via Tyrus on Tomcat 8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apache Tomcat 7.0 and later (and Eclipse Jetty 9.1) has built-in support for JSR-356 (aka `javax.websocket`).

There is no need to use the Tyrus compatibility layer on most JEE7 containers.

Just skip the entire Tyrus configuration issue and use the built-in features that expose `javax.websocket` support.

- [Jetty 9+](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/websocket-java.html)
- [Tomcat 8 How-To](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html)
- [Tomcat 7 How-To](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html)

Comment: I was definitely over-complicating things.  I must have needed a sanity check.  Everything works as expected per the docs, thanks Joakim!

Comment: A feature very useful of Tyrus is auto reconnect. I can't find anything related to autoreconnect in the built-in support for JSR-356.

Comment: auto reconnect is not part of the JSR-356 / javax.websocket spec or api

Comment: I tried to use Jetty 9.1 and 9.2. It worked but Jetty doesn't support CDI injection yet. So I want to use Tyrus in Jetty but so far without success.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt but is there a way to force use of Tyrus implementation instead of Tomcat's?

Comment: Possibly, but why?  The Tomcat implementation of JSR356 is better than Tyrus *(and I'm a Jetty developer!)*