# webSocket with Java Error during WebSocket handshake: 404

Tags: java, html, websocket

I am using webSocket with java 1.6 and HTML.

This is my reference example

https://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/java-ee-html5-websocket-example

When i go to http://localhost:8012/sessionLink/byteslounge/page.html

the error 404 is shown as below

**WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8012/sessionLink/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404**

Here is my code

**Server Side**

```
@ServerEndpoint("/websocket") 
public class WebSocketTest {

...

}
```

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var webSocket = 
    new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8012/sessionLink/websocket');   
    ...
 </script>
```

Am i setting the WebSocket wrongly ?

localhost:Port/path setted in tomcat/@ServerEndpoint

Comment: if i try new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8012/sessionLink/byteslounge') 
the error will be 302

Comment: A websocket handshake starts with a `GET` request. You can first try to open the `ws://localhost:8012/sessionLink/websocket` URL in your browser or whatever to ensure that the URL is reachable. If not, then your URL is incorrect. As the `/websocket` matches the `@ServerEndpoint` value, the error might be in `sessionLink`. The tutorial uses GlassFish with the Tyrus implementation. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20646865/4906586) you will need Tomcat 7+ which requires Java 7

Answer (score 2):

Try higher jdk version, java 1.6 or lower version doesn't support websocket.

Comment: even i imported the websocket-api.jar successfully??

Comment: Yes, I have met same problem, and your tomcat should also be Tomcat7.0.47 or later.